# How do I add personalized field to products?

Tags: custom-options, products

I would like to add some text fields , like attached.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The feature is called "Custom Options" and you can create them merely by editing your respective product and adding in the custom options as necessary.

[image]

Just add a simple product as normal, then when editing the page, in the lower left list of tabs, select "Custom Options" and add whatever you wish.